# Snowflake Primary key using alter statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

when I was adding primary key to snowflake table I saw something weird.

When I ran a query

```sql
ALTER TABLE "TESTSCHEMA".table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Above query works as expected. But when I tried to run

```sql
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS "TESTSCHEMA".table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Query was returning error `error line 0 at position 0 invalid identifier 'TOK_IF_EXISTS'`

Is this a bug or Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a primary key to the same column is expected to result in an error as provided below.

create table "TESTSCHEMA".table (id number);
--Statement executed successfully.

ALTER TABLE "TESTSCHEMA".table ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
--Statement executed successfully.

ALTER TABLE "TESTSCHEMA".table ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
--SQL compilation error: primary key already exists for table 'TABLE'

create table "TESTSCHEMA"."table1" (id number);
--Statement executed successfully.

ALTER TABLE "TESTSCHEMA"."table1" ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
--Statement executed successfully.

ALTER TABLE "TESTSCHEMA"."table1" ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
---SQL compilation error: primary key already exists for table 'table1'

The test case shared by you with the error details can be reported to Snowflake for validation

Comment: Manish is trying to do as:
create table table1 (id number); --Statement executed successfully. 
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID); --Statement executed successfully. 
drop table table1;
create table table1 (id number); --Statement executed successfully. 
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);--SQL compilation error: error line 0 at position 0 invalid identifier 'TOK_IF_EXISTS'

Comment: This error is reproducible and looks like a bug with 'if exists'
create schema test;
create table test.table2 (id number);
--Statement executed successfully.
ALTER TABLE test.table2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
--Statement executed successfully.
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS test.table2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
---SQL compilation error: error line 0 at position 0 invalid identifier 'TOK_IF_EXISTS'

Comment: create table test.table2 (id number);
--Statement executed successfully.
ALTER TABLE test.table2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
--Statement executed successfully.
ALTER TABLE test.table2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
--SQL compilation error: primary key already exists for table 'TABLE2'

Answer (score 1):

According to docs, it looks like a bug. Could you raise snowflake support case so that the behaviour can be validated? Thanks,

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html